# Filter values based on row conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

I am dealing with a relative easy problem that I don't know how to solve. Let's imagine I have the following dataframe:

```
Book  Word  Rel.Freq
   A   art      0.56
   A   car       0.4
   B   car      0.58
   B   dog      0.32
   C   art       0.5
   C   car      0.48
   C   dog      0.35
```

So, I want to have a dataframe only with the values that are the same for the column word. I need some function that would compare A, B, and C values in words and extract only the ones that are shared, that is only the ones that are repeated in all "books". I would also need a way to sum the Rel. Freq. values and obtain a mean based on the number of variables in book. I want a dataframe that would look like this:

```
word  Mean.Rel.Freq
 car           0.48
```

Comment: *"only the ones that are repeated in all "books""* But `art` in your expected output is *not* shared amongst `A`, `B`, `C` (whereas `car` *is* shared but does not show up). What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's considered polite around here to show what you have tried... Also, you may want to clarify your question, as it's not totally clear.

Comment: "art" is not repeated in all books (only in A and C), and the mean (or the sum) of 0.5 and 0.56 is certainly not 0.48.

Comment: try `df1 %>% group_by(Word) %>% filter(n_distinct(Book) == n_distinct(df1$Book)) %>% summarise(Mean.Rel.Freq = mean(Rel.Freq))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'Word', we `filter` those 'Word' where the number of distinct elements of 'Book' is equal to the distinct elements of 'Book' in the whole dataset and `summarise` the 'Rel.Freq' by taking the `mean` of it

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Word) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(Book) == n_distinct(.$Book)) %>% 
  summarise(Mean.Rel.Freq = mean(Rel.Freq))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#   Word  Mean.Rel.Freq
#   <chr>         <dbl>
#1 car           0.487
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to accomplish this task using the `tidyverse` suite of packages.

```
library(tidyverse)
# read in example data
df <- read_table("Book  Word  Rel.Freq
   A   art      0.56
    A   car       0.4
    B   car      0.58
    B   dog      0.32
    C   art       0.5
    C   car      0.48
    C   dog      0.35")
output <- df %>% 
  group_by(Word) %>% 
  summarize(
    n_books = n(),
    Mean.Rel.Freq = mean(Rel.Freq)
  ) 
# remove (if desired) the words with too-few books.
output <- output %>%
  filter(n_books < 3) # replace 3 with total number of books
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R version using `aggregate` and `Reduce` + `intersect` to find the consistent `Word`s:

```
aggregate(
    Rel.Freq ~ Word, data=dat, FUN=mean,
    subset = Word %in% Reduce(intersect, split(Word, Book))
)

#  Word  Rel.Freq
#1  car 0.4866667
```